# How to code sign "libffi.8.dylib" on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, code-signing, dylib, libffi

I have created a python application that I build into a Unix executable using Pyinstaller. The application runs fine until I attempt to code sign it. After code signing, I get the following error when attempting to run the executable:

> rosetta error: /var/db/oah/526469a4f4887ee6ca553807c3196c9533da7ef706c684764b83169e8658f8e2/ba3f613b849de777b4a89fdb1760c3c2343ac52546e2629e28f83fbf530a8f27/libffi.8.dylib.aot: unable to mmap __TEXT: 1

Is it possible to code sign dylib files such as this?

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Create conda environment with python v3.9
2. Activate environment and conda install numpy and pyinstaller
3. Create python script that imports numpy. Doesn't matter what the python script does, can just be one line as long as it imports numpy.
4. Use pyinstaller to build a distribution for the python file, with code signing like so:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --codesign-identity='<apple-id>' --osx-entitlements-file='<path-to-entitlements.plist-file>' <name-of-python-script>
```

5. Run the Unix executable that is produced inside the dist folder.

Comment: Same command you use for signing anything else (`codesign -f -s - your.dylib` if self-signing, modify appropriately if you have a "real" certificate). I assume you tried it and it failed, though?

Comment: I am able to code sign the file, but I receive the rosetta error when trying to run the app after code signing.

Comment: Could you provide steps sufficient to let someone else reproduce that error?

Comment: btw, you might want to check the system logs -- when the OS kills something due to a signature failure there's a message with relevant details.

Comment: Sure, I will modify the question and add the steps that lead to this error

Comment: (it's apparently been enough days since I last fixed a code signing bug that I don't have an example in dmesg anymore, but it roughly is of the form `kernel: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(..`, at least if something has a signature but has changed since it was made)

Comment: it's also worth checking `codesign --verify`, and comparing `codesign --display` between the Python executable and the library it's trying and failing to load)

Comment: Okay I tried running codesign --verify and codesign --display. Verify had no output for either file, and display outputted "Executable=<path-to-file>". Is this the expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question with the steps to reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't think you need to `codesign` the `libffi.8.dylib.aot`. I am running into the exact same error and even though `notarytool` accepts my app, it throws this error. doing the exact same thing with arm64 works perfectly. [It is this phenomenon, I assume](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725061). If anyone finds a solution for this, this would be really great!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer definitively, I think I have a solid guess.

The error you're encountering is likely due to the fact that the dynamic library (dylib) file `libffi.8.dylib` is not being properly signed during the PyInstaller build process.

If this is the case, here are the steps to manually sign the dylib file:

1. First, locate the `libffi.8.dylib` file in your PyInstaller bundle. It should be in the `dist/<your-app-name>/` directory.
2. Use the `codesign` command to sign the dylib file. Replace `<apple-id>` with your Apple Developer ID and `<path-to-libffi>` with the path to the `libffi.8.dylib` file:

```bash
codesign --force --verify --verbose --sign "<apple-id>" "<path-to-libffi>"
```

3. Verify that the dylib file is properly signed:

```bash
codesign --verify --verbose "<path-to-libffi>"
```

4. Now, rebuild your PyInstaller bundle with the same command you used before. The `libffi.8.dylib` file should now be properly signed and the error should be resolved.

If you're still encountering the error, it's possible that there are other dylib files that also need to be signed. You can use the `otool` command to check for any unsigned dependencies:

```bash
otool -L <path-to-your-executable>
```

This will list all the dylib files that your executable depends on. You can then manually sign these files using the `codesign` command as described above.

If this is not the case, please let me know. But I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I think the problem is not really the signing, but that the signing is not working correctly. I can codesign the file, but after I do it, the app breaks. It seems to be related to conda as you can read [here](https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/7899)

Comment: @gernophil I didn't see your comment on the answer prior to posting. However, given the question and information provided in it, as stated, this is a likely solution. From the perspective of this site, I think we should update the question before I would remove this answer. Or, I can create a multi-part solution based off our continued efforts. Will dig deeper on what you linked both here and above. To confirm, you've attempted manually signing the dependencies as I described? Or are positive it's not a solution without attempting it?

Comment: I did a little different. So the problem is, according to the notarytools, all files are correctly signed. Also I am not the one that asked  the question, but for me all files that are not correctly singed after the first notarytool I resign with `for i in "${files[@]}"; do
  codesign -s XXX --force --all-architectures --timestamp --options=runtime --deep --verbose=4 "$i"
done`. I'll make an answer later, but I am still testing.

Comment: This is a more direct link to the [discussion on github](https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/7899#discussioncomment-6896596).